# How to define a lemma towards inductive predicate that can not hold

Tags: isabelle

Recently, I have learned the inductive predicate of Isabelle, like even and the reflexive transitive clousre. It seems that we can easily derive the cases that the predicate hold, but when we need to prove some case that inductive predicate not hold, it can not work easily.

And I have done a case like below, a LTS system is used to accept list which can finally arrived. The notJoinLTSlemma lemma is hard for me to prove. Any help would be appreciated.

```
type_synonym ('q,'a) LTS = "('q * 'a set * 'q) set"

inductive LTS_is_reachable :: "(('q, 'a) LTS * ('q * 'q) set) ⇒ 'q ⇒ 'a list ⇒ 'q ⇒ bool" where
   LTS_Empty[intro!]:"LTS_is_reachable Δ q [] q"|
   LTS_Step1[intro!]:"(∃q''. (q, q'') ∈ snd Δ ∧ LTS_is_reachable Δ q'' l q') ⟹ LTS_is_reachable Δ q l q'" |
   LTS_Step2[intro!]:"(∃q'' σ. a ∈ σ ∧ (q, σ, q'') ∈ fst Δ ∧ LTS_is_reachable Δ q'' w q') ⟹ LTS_is_reachable Δ q (a # w) q'"

lemma joinLTSlemma:"LTS_is_reachable l q x p ⟹  LTS_is_reachable l p y q''⟹ LTS_is_reachable l q (x@y) q''"
  proof (induction rule: LTS_is_reachable.induct)
    case (LTS_Empty Δ q)
    then show ?case by auto
  next
    case (LTS_Step1 q Δ l q')
    then show ?case by auto
  next
    case (LTS_Step2 a q Δ w q')
    then show ?case by auto
  qed

lemma notJoinLTSlemma:"LTS_is_reachable l q x p ⟹  ¬ LTS_is_reachable l p y q''⟹ ¬ LTS_is_reachable l q (x@y) q''"
  nitpick
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your lemma `notJoinLTSlemma` does not hold, as `nitpick` already points out. Intuitively, the reason is that you're stating that "For *some* `p`, if `p` is reachable from `q` via `x`, and `q''` is not reachable from `p` via `y`, then `q''` is not reachable from `q` via `x@y`", which clearly is not true, since there may be another path in the LTS to reach `q''` from `q` via `x@y`. In order to see that, you can inspect the counter-example given by `nitpick`. Therefore, the correct statement is "For *all* `p`, ...", that is:

```
lemma notJoinLTSlemma:"∀p. LTS_is_reachable l q x p ∧ ¬ LTS_is_reachable l p y q'' ⟹ ¬ LTS_is_reachable l q (x@y) q''"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I agree with you. Another question is that how to prove this lemma, sorry that i have no idea.